# QEMU-KVM UEFI Secure Boot doesn't work

Tags: debian, qemu, kvm-switch, knoppix

I try to test this in QEMU-KVM:

https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/knoppix-uefi-en.html

My host OS is Debian 11 AMD64. I have *ovmf* .deb package sucessfully installed. I add OVMF to my virtual machine like this but doesn't work Secure Boot, only UEFI:

```
kvm \
   -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd \
   -monitor stdio \
   -cpu host \
   -smp cores=4,threads=2 \
   -k en \
   -machine accel=kvm \
   -m 4096 \
   -hda Knoppix.9.2.qcow2 \
   -net nic -net user \
   -usb -device usb-tablet \
   -rtc base=localtime \
   -name "Knoppix 9.2"
```

In physical UEFI, Secure Boot for Knoppix 9.2 works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does not work and how exactly does it not work?

Comment: @Daniel B: With physical UEFI Knoppix shows "Failed to start loader" (like you can see on my URL link). With QEMU UEFI goes directly to Knoppix boot menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OVMF documentation says you must use the `-pflash` parameter if you want Secure Boot:

> - Use OVMF for QEMU firmware (3 options available)
>
>   - Option 1: QEMU 1.6 or newer; Use QEMU -pflash parameter
>
>     - QEMU/OVMF will use emulated flash, and fully support UEFI variables
>     - Run qemu with: -pflash path/to/OVMF.fd
>     - Note that this option is required for running SecureBoot-enabled builds
>       (-D SECURE_BOOT_ENABLE).

The [Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot/VirtualMachine) suggests you’ll also want some EFI variables file. The complete invocation could look somewhat like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
 -accel kvm \
 -smp 2 \
 -m 2048 \
 -machine pc-q35-2.5 \
 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=./OVMF_CODE_4M.secboot.fd \
 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=./OVMF_VARS_4M.ms.fd \
 -drive file=./ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.iso,readonly=on,format=raw,index=0,media=cdrom \
 -boot menu=on
```

Note that because EFI variables can (and will) change, you’ll need your own copy of the file. The firmware does not change, so you don’t have to copy it locally. Depending on your Linux distribution, you may have a separate OVMF code file that has Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: That means you probably did not use the correct variables file. I have now tested this using the OVMF package from Debian Bullseye and can confirm it works as documented. I have updated the answer with the precise command I used.

Comment: It's works now! --> [link](https://i.imgur.com/0efrDT8.png) [link](https://i.imgur.com/sUQOgvn.png) . Thank you very very much, @Daniel B.